# OS X security version?

Tags: macos

I am trying to find out the most recent security patch that has been installed on a system (e.g. 2015-006). In this case, it is the latest Yosemite (10.10.5). Neither the version nor the build number are helpful here, as security patches do not seem to update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All security updates are recorded in receipts folder located here:

```
ls -ltr /var/db/receipts
```

If you list the receipts folder, you can see the most recent updates installed.

Comment: At least on Yosemite, /var/db/receipts is a folder. Still didn't find the security patch though, which might mean it is unpatched 10.10.5.

Comment: @stands2reason, Yeah it should read ls -ltr, vice tail. Working late...

Comment: I tested installing the 2016-001 update, and sure enough it's there now. Don't forget to pipe it into `grep com.apple.pkg.update.security` to filter results.